# Access microphone with gphoto2

Tags: ffmpeg, microphone, audio-recording, gstreamer

There is [a lot of documentation](https://medium.com/nerdery/dslr-webcam-setup-for-linux-9b6d1b79ae22) for using gphoto2 to use a DSRL as a webcam. With those techniques, the system sees the camera as a new video device

```
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

or

```
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc fd=0 ! decodebin name=dec ! queue ! videoconvert ! tee ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0
```

But what about **sound**? Is there a way to plug the DSLR **microphone** to my system so I can use the **camera audio** too? It seems that gphoto2 as a `--capture-sound` parameter, so it seems it is ready for that, but then what? How to plug ffmpeg or gst-launch so they can use the audio?

Comment: In 2020 the developers of gphoto2 said that no driver was implementing `--capture-sound` yet.
https://github.com/gphoto/libgphoto2/issues/510#issuecomment-633250126